# Pan Gesture Recognizer Interrupts UIButton Hightlight

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uipangesturerecognizer

I added a UIPanGestureRecognizer and UITapGestureRecognizer to a UIButton for a customize effect. But when I panning on the button, the highlighting which caused by previous tapping went disappeared. How can I get rid of it ?Or give me a way of manually handling the highlight effect of a view while being touched. 
Thanks.

Comment: dude do post ur code.... without it we are blind :)